# EntityManager.clear() caused LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I kinda facing a challenge where I have an entity with uni-directional OnetoMany list So we have `Track` and list of `TrackVersions versions`

```
Track {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "track", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // lazy by default
    private final List<TrackVersion> versions = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Then I have a service to delete `TrackVersions` by `Track`

```
.....

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional
public void deleteTrackVersions(Track track) {
    entityManger.flush();
    entityManger.clear();
    
    trackVerionRepo.deleteTrackVerions(track.getVersions); // This is a JPQL query that deletes track version where track version IN (? givenTrackVersions param)

   ..... some other logic

}
```

However whenever `trackVerionRepo.deleteTrackVerions(track.getTrackVersions)` executes it fails with

`failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Track.versions, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: Track.versions, could not initialize proxy - no Session`

What happened is The `entityManager.clear()` cleared the persistence context causing `verisons` which is lazily loaded to be dropped. So any consecutive request to load it will cause `LazyInitializedExcpetion`

But as per my understanding as long as there is an opened `Transaction` hence an opened `HibernateSession` so there is no reason for that `LazyException` to happen, that lazy collection should have been loaded again!

Note: I'm aware of the similar Posts of `LazyInitilizationExcpetion` errors in hibernate but in this case, I'm asking specifically why it happened after the `entityManager.clear()`

Comment: Hello, could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to `entityManager.clear()` call. According to the [specifications](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/entitymanager#clear()), once you call `entityManager.clear()` all of the managed entities in your persistence context will be detached - mainly, the `Track` entity received in the `deleteTrackVersions` method parameter. And, as you said, the `@OneToMany` mapping use lazy loading by default.

Once the `Track` entity becomes detached, it doesn't matter if still there's an active transaction. You won't be able to retrieve the related `TrackVersion` entities unless you reattach the `Track` entity first.

To reattach an entity to the persistence context you can use `entityManager.merge()` method. Nevertheless, considering the code you provided, I'd just remove the `entityManager.clear()` call.

As an unrelated note, you can't trust the lazy loading mapping configuration blindly; it's a hint to the persistence provider, but it isn't guaranteed to be observed.